# Generic type of Kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin, generics

- What is the difference between these two codes?

'''

```
class Cage<T: Animal>(var animal: T)

class CovariantCage<in T: Animal>(private var t: T?){
    fun getId(): Int? = t?.id
    fun getName(): String?= t?.name
    fun getContentType(t: T?){ println(t?.id)}
    fun printAnimalInfo() : String = "Animal ${t?.id} is called ${t?.name}"
}

//_______________________________________________________________________________________________

class Cage2(var animal: Animal)

class CovariantCage2(private var t: Animal?){
    fun getId(): Int? = t?.id
    fun getName(): String?= t?.name
    fun getContentType(t: Animal?){ println(t?.id)}
    fun printAnimalInfo() : String = "Animal ${t?.id} is called ${t?.name}"
}
```

'''

My animal classes

'''

```
open class Animal(open val id:Int, open val name: String)

data class Dog(override val id: Int, override val name: String) : Animal(id, name)

data class Cat(override val id: Int, override val name: String) : Animal(id, name)
```

'''

- When i should use generic class?

Comment: When T can vary. In your case T is of type Animal and Animal is a final class, meaning subclassing is not possible. Therefore there is no reason to use Generics – T will always be of type Animal. Now when you change Animal to be an 'open' or 'abstract' class and you create subsclasses like Dog and Cat, then using Generics makes sense.

Comment: Sorry i confused, My animal class alredy open data class,

'open class Animal(open val id:Int, open val name: String)'

Comment: Well, your question does not state that fact.

Comment: I edit question and added my animal classes.

Comment: Read through this topic in the Java documentation. The syntax is different, but the concepts are the same. It will help you understand the uses of generics. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Here is the first of 3 articles which I found very useful to explain Covariance and Contravariance in Kotlin 
https://typealias.com/guides/illustrated-guide-covariance-contravariance/

it is quite different from Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Cage<T>` vs `Cage2`:
   If you want function that works, e.g., with cats specifically, you need `Cage<Cat>`, as `Cage2` can contain instance of any subclass of Animal.
2. `CovariantCage<T>` vs `CovariantCage2`: they should be actually called Contravariant cages, as `in` makes type parameter contravariant, meaning that it reverts subtyping relation, e.g, if `A2` is subtype of `A1` then `ContravariantCage<A1>` is subtype of `ContravariantCage<A2>`. In your case `ContravariantCage<T>` is something that can process (consume) animal of type `T`, but not return (produce) animal of type `T`, so it's logical that if you have function that, e.g., accepts cage with cat, it should also accept cage with animal, as anything you can do with animal, you can also do with cat:

```
fun foo(catCage: ContravariantCage<Cat>) = ...
val animalCage: ContravariantCage<Animal> = ...
foo(animalCage)
```

`ContravariantCage<in T : Animal>` states exactly that. `ContravariantCage2` on the other hand doesn't have type variance at all, as it doesn't have type parameter.